# SQL insert subquery error

Tags: sql, insert, subquery

I have an insert query with two subqueries:

```
INSERT INTO Work_Order (ID ,BRANCHID,BRANDID)   
VALUES (66),
SELECT ID FROM Brands WHERE NAME = 'branch'
SELECT ID FROM Branches WHERE NAME = 'brand'
```

I know it's not a correct syntax but I need the correct one,
the ID must be 66 and BRANCHID,BRANDID are foreign keys for another tables

Comment: if you are inserting something into a database by fetching that something from another table, then your design is wrong. I say rethink.

Comment: look I am not a DB professional , the design consists of 3 tables the first is the one that I am inserting to, BRANCHID is a foreign key for another table called branches and the same for brands , the user writes  the name of the branch and I will insert its ID , I think it's a good design, isn't it??

Comment: oh stupid of me, thats fine, I for a moment thought you were inserting 'branch', 'brand' etc and not their ids. Apologies.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your subqueries return more than one row, you have to decide how to combine the values.  The following query assumes you want all combinations:

```
INSERT INTO Work_Order (ID ,BRANCHID, BRANDID)
    select 66, branches.id, brands.id
    from brands cross join branches
    where branches.NAME = 'branch' and
          brands.NAME = 'brand'
```

(I changed the where clause to look for the name within the same table as the name . . . branches.Name = 'branch' rather than branches.name = 'brand'.)

Answer (score 4):

`66` is a literal, use it and two subselects in your `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO Work_Order (ID ,BRANCHID,BRANDID) 
SELECT
  66 AS ID,
  (SELECT ID FROM Brands WHERE NAME='branch') AS BRANCHID,
  (SELECT ID FROM Brands WHERE NAME='brand') AS BRANDID
```

MySQL is lenient about the existence of a `FROM` clause, so this ought to work.  Many other RDBMS would require you to put in a `FROM` clause with some table even though it isn't used in the `SELECT` (like Oracle's `Dual` table).

Answer (score 1):

This is how it worked perfectly with me

```
INSERT INTO Work_Order (NUMBER,BRANDID,BRANCHID)    
SELECT 66,B.ID,Br.ID
FROM Brands as B,Branches as Br
WHERE B.NAME = 'brand' AND Br.NAME = 'branch'
```